# Python string replace

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I have this code:

```
    ALPHABET1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    key = "TES"
    ALPHABET2 = key + ALPHABET1
    count_result = ALPHABET2.count("T")
    if (count_result > 1):
    ALPHABET3 = ALPHABET1.replace("T","")
    ALPHABET2 = key + ALPHABET3         
    print(ALPHABET2)
```

I want to be able to put the keyword at the start of the alphabet string to create a new string without repeating the letters in the keyword. I'm having some problems doing this though. I need the keyword to work for all letters as it will be user input in my program. Any suggestions?

Comment: string is a "tuple" of values. You could make a set of letters, than convert back to string(draw back for simple implementation is that order it's changed). But I think a simple parser-loop for eache letter, in a list comprehension-it may be the right solution for you. If it sound strange, tell me and I expand this in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You don't need to make the alphabet yourself, `import string` and use `string.ascii_uppercase`; and
2. You can use a `for` loop to work through the characters in your key.

To illustrate the latter:

```
for c in key:
    alphabet = alphabet.replace(c, "")
```

Better yet, a `list` is mutable, so you can do:

```
alpha = [c for c in string.ascii_uppercase if c not in key]
alpha.extend(set(key))
```

Comment: Neither of the approaches I outline needs to know the length of the key. A `for` loop works through however many characters there are.

Comment: yeah.. i figured it out just after posting :))

Answer (score 0):

its easy and clean to do this with a regex

```
import re

ALPHABET1   = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key         = "TES"
newalphabet = key.upper() + re.sub(r'%s'%'|'.join(key.upper()), '', ALPHABET1)
```

or with a list comprehension like @jonrsharpe suggested